# Download files metadata from cloud storage with Java

Tags: google-cloud-storage, bucket

I'm trying to down data from my cloud storage but I didn't manage to do it by myself. I'm running this code :

```
public static byte[] downloadBucket(String bucketName, String fileName) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
  Storage storage = StorageFactory.getService();

  Get get = null;
  ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  try {
      get = storage.objects().get(bucketName, fileName);
      get.executeAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

I except some JSON but I only get this so far :

[B@fe18270

What should I do or what did I miss here ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You're returning `ByteArray` so I guess this is valid. If you would like to receive JSON, you have to convert it once again.

Comment: You're right, my code is ok and i actually get the JSON I expected. Thanks !

Comment: Perhaps you can promote @Rafal's comment to an answer?